# SharePoint Document Library document delete

Tags: sharepoint-addin, event-receivers, event-handlers

Please suggest your solution for the following scenario:

A user deletes the document from document library and an e-mail has to be triggered to the admin notifying the information about the document deleted recently along with the option to Approve\Reject. If the Admin approves it, the document stays in Recycle Bin and if Rejected, the document gets restored to the document library.

I came across some articles about 'event receiver' which can trigger an e-mail but couldn't find any coding the recycle bin and deletion. Is there any other workaround to implement the same?

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be easier to create a workflow that "Flags a document for removal".

Your workflow could:

- Update a status column to 'pending deletion'
- Issue a task/email to an approver to approve the deletion
- If approved, the document would be deleted If not, the status would change to 'rejected'

In the default view for the library, you should only show items where the status column is not equal to 'pending deletion'. That way, end users wouldn't see documents pending deletion.

You could probably get this done with SharePoint Designer.

If you wanted to go with the Event Receiver route, you would probably need to have an Event Receiver on the Document Library that would fire a workflow to assign a task to the approver. That workflow would need to have a guid-reference to the deleted item so it could be retrieved from the recycling bin.

These links should help if you go with the Event Receiver Route:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sprecyclebinitem.restore.aspx
http://zimmergren.net/technical/starting-a-sharepoint-workflow-from-code-event-receiver

Comment: +1 I've used soft deleting like this before and it works well. The only caveat is that if this needs to be implemented in more than 1 place, then the event receiver approach becomes a better alternative because of the maintenance headaches it prevents.